# Android Studio with custom view inflate layout from AAR

Tags: android, static-libraries

### Background

I have two projects:

- Library

  - AAR (Android Library)
  - Unit test module
- App

  - MainActivity
  - Import AAR

The custom view is implemented in the AAR library, it inflate an extra layout from resource:

```
public class MyCustomView extends ViewGroup {
...
public MyCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ctor(context, null, 0);
}
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctor(context, attrs, 0);
}
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    ctor(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
private void ctor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    View rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.mycustomview, this);
    ...
}
```

The view works perfectly on unit test module, both on phone and AS's preview.

---

### Problem

On the second app project, `rootView` becomes `null` when initiated from  Android Studio's preview, whereas there is no problem on phone.

Am I missing some configuration or is this a bug from Android Studio?

### Note

My current workaround is to duplicate the layout file mycustomview.xml into test app's project, Android Studio's preview then works fine with that. But I really don't want to pollute the project space and I'm sure it will get out-sync someday and bite me hard.

I could also hack with [View.IsInEditMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode()) as a last resort.

PS: Android Studio Version: 2.1.2, Build Tool 23.0.3, SDK 24

This does not appear in the [Known issues](http://tools.android.com/knownissues).

Comment: got same problem, did you find solution ?

Comment: Any proper solution to this ?